# How to get top hits by document type

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a number of simple queries I'm sending that look roughly like this:

My question is how to sort the results such that I get at least some top 'n' hits from each document type.   I've been playing with boosting, and some results from docType1 are so powerful that with a limit of 30, they push all relevant hits from the other document types out of the search results.

```
{ 
   from: 0, limit: 30,
   index: 'myIndex',
   type: 'docType1,docType2,docType3',
   body: {
     query: {
       simple_query_string: {
          query: 'foo',
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I've looked into sorting, but that's not really what I want.  I've also looked into aggregation, but I'm having trouble finding the right formula that would get things there.  I've also looked into `top_hits` but frankly am having a tough time understanding the documentation or whether this is applicable to the use case.